# Spotlight Cmd+Enter to open containing folder does not work

Tags: finder, spotlight

When you type something in spotlight, highlight a result and hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it should open the containing folder in finder ([For reference](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/)). However, it does not work on my OSX 10.8.2 MBPR. The finder application comes to the foreground (the finder menu bar is shown on top of the screen), but no finder window on the location gets opened.

I have BetterTouchTool installed and thought this could cause it somehow, but, having it deactivated, keeps happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [bug in 10.8.2](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2012/10/04/aesendmessage-bug-in-mac-os-x-10-8-2/) that intermittently makes revealing files in Finder stop working. When that happens, Archive Utility also stops responding whenever you try to extract archives.

As a workaround, you can terminate the appleeventsd process from Activity Monitor or with `sudo killall -kill appleeventsd` (without -kill the process is sent a TERM signal and other processes stop responding). The issue will probably return in a few days or hours though.

Comment: thanks. Archive Utility stopped working months ago like you wrote, I just replaced it with Unarchiver and already forgot about it.

Comment: I can confirm that 8 years later and on Big Sur, this problem is still present. After killing appleeventsd process, Command + Click opens the containing folder of a file again.

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds like you have another conflicting keyboard shortcut that’s overriding the default.

In System Preferences > Keyboard choose “Keyboard Shortcuts” and look around. If another shortcut is tied to ⌘⏎ then you may need to change it; or simpler, click “Restore Defaults”.